# Explain the line in context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was reading one article and could not understand the following part in bold.
Tha article is basically about the BCCI refusing to take the recommendations of supreme court and so have to pay the price of defiance.

> It was therefore inevitable that the court would seek to send out a message that it **will not brook any wilful defiance**. Despite the court making the Lodha panel reforms **binding on the BCCI through its July 18 verdict, the BCCI appeared to defy it.**

My questions are

- For 1st part, does it say that the court will not let any kind of disobey to its recommendations happen?
- What binding is thw author talking about? Also, how did the BCCI defy it?

I read the article from the following link: 
http://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/The-price-of-defiance/article16979003.ece

Comment: Do you know the definition of **brook**?  What do you think is **binding**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Brook means tolerate or allow, thus the first bolded part means the court refuses to allow purposeful ("wilful") disobedience. You are correct.
2. The author is talking about the bindings of the reforms on the "BCCI". That is, the court made laws the "BCCI" had to follow. In the article, these laws appeared to be about the manner that cricket is administered. It is assumed that the "BCCI" did not follow the ordered laws on cricket administration and was punished.

-Please suggest anything that could make my response better in the future!
;)

Comment: Correct on the use of "will not brook defiance", however the details of the binding and how the BCCI defied it are not in the quote.  I'd have to read the rest of the article to find out.